# Выдает ошибку " *** missing separator "

Tags: linux, c, separator

Выдает ошибку Makefile:3:*** missing separator

```
#NAkefile for
hello : main.c
    gcc -c hello main.c
clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: замените пробелы на символ табуляции в начале 3-й и 5-й строк.

Comment: я изначально использовал табуляцию

Comment: тогда такой ошибки возникать просто не должно. ещё раз убедитесь, что в файле на самом деле в начале 3-й и 5-й строки находятся символы табуляции, а не пробелы. смотрите, например, с помощью программы *hexdump*: `$ hexdump -C файл`. символ табуляции имеет код `09`, а пробел ­— `20`